# Are ArcView and Basic license levels of ArcMap the same?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, proximity, basic-license-level

I need the near(dist) command, but I think I need to have a more advanced version than what I have.

I have:

ArcMap 10.0 (Build 4000)

ArcGIS desktop 10 service pack 4 (Build 4000)

license type: ArcView

Is that a basic programme? if so, how does one upgrade?

Comment: Yes, the "ArcView" license was the previous term to the current "Basic" license. Based on the help, you would need to upgrade to a full ArcInfo license. Your profile says you're studying for a Ph.D. Check with your university to see if they have a site license or individual licenses available.

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to do with the Near tool, you may be able to accomplish the same thing with a Spatial Join - which can be done with a Basic license. And to finish out mkennedy's info on license level/name, Editor = Standard, Info = Advanced.

Answer (score 1):

As [commented by @mkennedy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/149636/are-arcview-and-basic-license-levels-of-arcmap-the-same/207940#comment219099_149636):

> Yes, the "ArcView" license was the previous term to the current
>   "Basic" license. Based on the help, you would need to upgrade to a
>   full ArcInfo license. Your profile says you're studying for a Ph.D.
>   Check with your university to see if they have a site license or
>   individual licenses available.